# How to set an environment variable to a specific stage of gitlab ci pipeline

Tags: automation, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, cicd

I am using GitLab ci as my pipeline for build -> test -> deploy_dev -> deploy_prod.
Some time ago I added a step called deploy private to deploy to some private dev environments.

To support this feature in the pipeline I need to edit an environment variable only for that stage in the pipeline (let's call that stage in pipeline deploy_private).

A few key points:

1. I need to change this environment variable, it is not fixed - I mean that each developer can name his private dev environment as he likes and it is not a fixed environment variable.
2. I do not want to override the environment variable to the whole pipeline, other stages in the pipeline use that environment variable already.
3. I do not want to override the environment variable to each job manually, we have about 10 jobs under deploy private and this will take too much time and it is a mundane task.
4. Making the pipeline less cupeled to that environment variable is the correct way to go, but this is a huge and old project so this is a risky task that could take weeks.

I tried to run the whole pipeline with a new environment variable - but this is not a valid option in my case.
Currently, I am editing the environment variable manually in GitLab UI, but this takes a long time, it is error-prone, and having 10 jobs in that stage of the pipeline means that this takes about 2-3 minutes
[image]

Answer (score 0):

After searching for a while, and opening a feature ticket for Gitlab, I decided to on a simple but creative solution.
Taking the environment variable from the git branch name, by a branch naming convention we started to use in our projects.

see [this link](https://teachtimes.medium.com/automation-in-branch-name-convention-16659cb2e65d) for more details.

Code for gitlab-ci.yaml file looks something like this

```
 .set_stage_deploy_private: &set_stage_deploy_private
  - echo "Please note that deploy private does not set the STAGE env var by 
            default"
  - echo "You can set it manually or follow Branch Name Convention 
            (See README.me file)"
  - echo "Your branch name is $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
  # using Shell Parameter Expansion to extract STAGE after the . sign
  - if [ -z "$STAGE" ] || [ -z "${STAGE// }" ] ; 
      then echo "STAGE was not set - will set STAGE from Branch Name Convention" ;
      STAGE="${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME##*.}" ; 
    fi
  - echo "Your STAGE is $STAGE"
  - echo "Verifying the STAGE is properly set ... "
  # if STAGE is empty (was not set as env var and not with Branch Name 
  # Convention) abort build
  - if [ -z "$STAGE" ] || [ -z "${STAGE// }" ] ; 
      then echo "STAGE is empty! STAGE was not set properly exiting..." ; 
      exit 1 ; 
    fi
  # if STAGE is "sandbox" or "prod" abort the build
  - if [ "$STAGE" = "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME" ] || [ "$STAGE" = "sandbox" ] || 
          [ "$STAGE" = "prod" ] ; 
        then echo "STAGE is not allowed! STAGE was not set properly 
            exiting..." ; 
        exit 1 ; 
    fi
  - echo "Deploying service $SERVICE with stage $STAGE"

# Matrix deployment job for all 8 services to private stack 
deploy_private:
  extends:
    - .deploy-dev
  variables:
    AWS_ACCOUNT_ID: $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID_DEV
    AWS_REGION: $AWS_REGION_DEV
  environment: private/${SERVICE}
  parallel:
    matrix:
      - SERVICE:
          - rabo
          - rai
          - rams
          - raop
          - ras
          - raw
          - rps
          - school
  before_script:
    - *set_stage_deploy_private    # will set STAGE env var to cache
  script:
    - *deploy_private              # rest of deployment logic
```